# How to get the multiple child process exit status whether it is failed or success in linux shell scripting

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

How can return or get the exit status of child process individually .

here is the child process

```
process()
{
    rem=$(( $PID % 2 ))

    if [ $rem -eq 0 ]
    then
        echo "Number is even $PID"
        exit 0
    else
        echo "Number is odd $PID"
        exit 1
    fi

  echo "fred $return"
  exit $rem
}

for i in {1..100}; do
   process $i &
   PID="$!"
   echo "$PID:$file" 
   PID_LIST+="$PID "
done

for process in ${PID_LIST[@]};do
    echo "current_PID=$process"
   wait $process
   exit_status=$?
   echo "$process  => $exit_status"
done

echo " The END"
```

what i am expecting is every even number exit status must be 0 and odd number exit status must be 1. 
but the above script gives the below output, where the few even number has exit status 1 and few odd number has exit status 0.
can some one correct me.

```
16687:
16688:
/home/nzv1dtr/sample_file.sh: line 3: % 2 : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "% 2 ")
16689:
Number is odd 16687
16690:
Number is even 16688
16691:
Number is odd 16689
current_PID=16687
16687  => 1
current_PID=16688
16688  => 1
current_PID=16689
Number is even 16690
16689  => 0
current_PID=16690
16690  => 1
current_PID=16691
16691  => 0
```

Comment: You are using the PID as exit status. PID (`$!`) is a label, not a return code. the exit status (`$?`) should be nonzero on fail, but might be even, so you also can't use modulus unless you *KNOW* your process can never have an exit of 2 or any other even number.

Comment: Use `return` instead of `exit` in your function. Also, you cannot (easily) get the exit code (`$?`) of a forked process (`&`), because you don't know when it exists.

Answer (score 1):

There is a bit more going on in here. Essentially you're on the right track, `wait` can collect and report return status of a child, like so:

```
for i in {0..20}; do
        if [[ $((i % 2)) -eq 1 ]]; then
                /bin/true &
        else
                /bin/false &
        fi
        a[${i}]=$!
done

for i in ${a[@]}; do
        wait ${i}; echo "PID(${i}) returned: $?"
done
```

Why do you not see the same?

Well, for starters, `process` is not (really) a process, but a function (hence as mentioned in comment, `exit` is not the correct way to terminate it, if called in a script, it would terminate the whole script, not just the function). It does become a process, but how is part of it. Shell will spawn a new subshell and run your function (hence the exit is not deadly to the outer script). What status your shell was at the time it spawned it is important here.

You're also comparing to `${PID}` which is actually last subshell's `PID` and for first call yields an error. You probably wanted to look for `$$`, except for the above paragraph would mean, all functions (sub-shells) would use the same value (of the parent process).

Equipped with that information, a minimal change to your script would be to use `$$` in the `process` function, export the function so that we can use it in a new shell instance we `fork`, we track `PID` of that new shell:

```
process()
{
    rem=$(( $$ % 2 ))
...
}

export -f process
for i in {1..100}; do
   bash -c "process" $i &
...
```

Comment: Hi, Ondrej your answere helped me, but could you please explain ```a[${i}]=$!``` i know it is an array but i am wondering about the "a" it is not declared in the script so, how does it works. Thank you

Comment: @ongrej, I tried same logic with my script, could you please explain what is worng with my script, I have updated the question please look into it.

Comment: ad array: you do not need to declare variables, even arrays, you can just assign (also to items).